# Filter VSTS Build Artifiacts for release based at "triggering" branch

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

**Context:**

I have two YAML Build Definitions in the same Azure DevOps Git repo. The YAML files are sitting on separate folders `component1` and `component2`, the build triggers are filtered based on the path. Here are the YAML files:

First file in folder `component1`:

```
name: 1.0$(Rev:.rr)
trigger:
    branches:
        include:
        - master
        - release/*
    paths:
        include:
            - component1
resources:
    - repo: self
steps:
- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: My Copy Step
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: 'component1'
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: Publish Artifacts
```

Second file in folder `component2`:

```
name: 1.0$(Rev:.rr)
trigger:
    branches:
        include:
        - master
        - release/*
    paths:
        include:
            - component2
resources:
    - repo: self
steps:
- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: My Copy Step
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: 'component2'
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: Publish Artifacts
```

I also have a Release pipeline that is triggered by both artifacts and deploy the latest of these both artifacts.

[image]

[image]

**My goal:**

What I want to achieve is when the release is automatically created, I want to filter the artifacts so that the release uses the latest artifacts that originated from the "triggering" branch.

So if I put it in a sequence, it would be like this:

1. I change a file in `component1` in the `master` branch.
2. The `component1` build definition kicks in and creates the artifact based on the `master` branch.
3. The release pipeline is triggered due to the creation of the artifact in step 2, and the artifacts used for this release is the latest versions that originated from the `master` branch, for both artifacts

Then I do the following sequence:

1. I change a file in `component2` in the `release` branch.
2. The `component2` build definition kicks in and creates the artifact based on the `release` branch.
3. The release pipeline is triggered due to the creation of the artifact in step 2, and the artifacts used for this release is the latest versions that originated from the `release` branch. NOT the latest from the previous sequence, for both artifacts.

**Problem/Question:**

It seems that there is no option so far to choose the source branch dynamically. I tried to use the `$(Release.Artifacts.{Artifact alias}.SourceBranchName)` variable for the "Default version" field, but that would not trigger the release.

Is my goal doable? And if yes, how?

Comment: why not use a separate build definition for each branch?

Comment: This limits the dynamic nature of choosing which branch to build from. It's rigid and high maintenance. Not appealing to me.

Comment: What's the output you're trying to achieve here? It's not clear from your abstract description to determine the value of what you're doing. This approach seems somewhat complicated and will require inspection of a build's source before you can easily determine its constituent parts.

Comment: There is a lot of historical constraints in the current situation that I am taking as-is. 

Nonetheless, if I try to elaborate more; think of it as a micro-services repo (dirty word, I know!). The system is composed of these components, each component has an artifact as a result of the build pipeline.

On the git commit level, these components should be working fine together, but they diverge at the artifact level since we want to build each component separately; we don't want to build all components if we have changed one only. does this make clearer?

Comment: I would look at maybe using Azure DevOps Artefacts as your build output for the components and then include your item(s) from there instead. It still doesn't really make 100% sense to me though :)

Comment: That's alright, I think I am bound to the historical constraints we have. Thanks a lot @SimonW for your time in this :)